# Bootstrap action for EMR

Tags: emr

While bootstapping on `AWS EMR` - I am getting the following. Any clues how to resolve it?

`/mnt/var/lib/bootstrap-actions/1/STAR: /lib/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /mnt/var/lib/bootstrap-actions/1/STAR)`

Comment: bootstrap is no special than running script in every node. So I think you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830650/how-do-i-fix-a-version-glibc-2-14-not-found-error

Answer (score 0):

It's probably caused by not having high enough version of libc6.

You can SSH into the EC2 instance the EMR job created by following this: [Open an SSH Tunnel to the Master Node](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-ssh-tunnel.html)

Then update the packages, for example, if your instance uses ubuntu, you should do `sudo apt-get update`. The command depends on which distribution of linux you are creating on your ec2 instance. The default emr job uses Debian, and Amazon linux is built based on redhat.

See if this would work.

If this is actually the problem, you can add this update package command (with ignoring Y/N prompt) at the start of your bootstrap script.